# Use iPhone camera as an input sensor for EV3

Tags: ev3, bluetooth, ios

As EV3 has Bluetooth builtin as well as iPhone too, is there a way to connect them somehow so that iPhone could send data from the camera via Bluetooth to an EV3 brick?

As a more general question, can I make iPhone send/receive data to/from the brick via Bluetooth, e.g. commands, with Objective C or other ways?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't come across any existing projects like this yet, but there is nothing stopping you from doing this yourself. I would suggest writing an app for your phone in Obj-C and just remote controlling the EV3 via bluetooth.

The bluetooth communication uses the RFCOMM profile. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677386/bluetooth-connection-to-lego-mindstorms-ev3-brick-from-ios-app) might give you some hints on getting the bluetooth connection.

You can find the EV3 communication protocol specifications in the hardware developers kit that is linked in [this blog post](http://botbench.com/blog/2014/02/19/ev3-build-your-own-block-and-hdksdk-docs-available/).

Hopefully this is is enough to get you started.